# How to change group directory in Linux?

Tags: command-line, directory

In Linux I created a group (managers) and a directory (/engineers).  The group in not in the directory.  What command do I use/what do I type to put the managers group in the /engineers directory?

Comment: Do you mean you want the directory to have the group `managers`? Like the group which you can find out by typing `ll /engineers`? If so, you can run `sudo chown :managers /engineers`.

Comment: Instead of `chown :managers` you can also use `chgrp managers`, actually.

Comment: What do you mean by *"put the managers group in the /engineers directory"*? You can [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you can use `chgrp` to change the group:

```
sudo chgrp managers /engineers
```

where `managers` is the group name and `/engineers` is the directory name.